# Nomenclature does not appear when compiling

Tags: nomenclature

The abbreviation.tex file does contain all abbreviations in the following format.

However, the nomenclature llist is not compiled. It does generate it on the overleaf online compiler when I just enter what is in the abbrevitions.tex file. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[affil-it]{authblk}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,gensymb,upgreek}
\usepackage[lmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{enumerate}
%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\renewcommand*{\nompreamble}{\begin{multicols}{2}}
\renewcommand*{\nompostamble}{\end{multicols}}
\makenomenclature
\makeindex
\setlength{\columnsep}{3em}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric-comp,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{complete.bib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{float}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{0pt}}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\flushright
\fontseries{b}\fontsize{80}{100}\selectfont}{\fontseries{b}\fontsize{100}{130}\selectfont \textcolor{gray75}\thesection\hsp}{0pt}{\ \\\Huge \bfseries}[]


\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing
\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\begin{multicols}{2}
\nomenclature{$\rho$}{density}
\end{multicols}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\printbibliography
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: unrelated to your question but `\fontsize{500}{100}\selectfont` is 500pt letters specified to fit in lines 100pt apart which is doomed to failure. 18cm high font is quite big..... Please edit the example so it is in a form that people can run it to see the issue.

Comment: I did correct that now.

Comment: we still can not run the example it includes files we have not got.  Have you run makindex to generate the nomenclature file?

Comment: I corrected that now. Yes, I have run makeindex multiple times before I started compiling. (I also deleted any related files already to exclude spill-over). I also ran the exact code in the overleaf-compiler and it worked. So I do not anticipate any the syntax-errors per se.

Answer (score 1):

Your example produces

[image]

if you save as `file.tex` and run

```
pdflatex file
makeindex file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls 
pdflatex file
pdflatex file
```

Comment: I do not know why the nomenclature list is not getting filled. Whe I run the Makeindex in the TeXmaker I get this : This is makeindex, version 2.16 [MiKTeX 22.1]. Scanning input file thesis.idx...done (0 entries accepted, 0 rejected). Nothing written in thesis.ind. Transcript written in thesis.ilg.    Is there a way to inlcude alle entries in the nomenclature file regardless of if there were actually used ?

Comment: you are just running makeindex with the default input `.idx` (which is empy unless you have `\index` commands for a real index) you need to use the fom  I show here to use the separate .nlo file and the special nomncl.ist makeindex style that comes with the package @Thorek

Comment: I do not understand how to implement that. I am only familiar with the texmaker environment and followed these instructions: https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Nomenclatures Do put these four lines in parenthesis after \makenomenclature such as  \makenomenclature{file.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o file.nls}? Or do have to put them somewhere else? Sry this lack of understandind.

Comment: I would literally just type the commands I show on the commandline, although you must be able to do that through your editor.  Altrnatively if you get texmaker to use `latexmk`  then I believe laexmk will take care of calling makeindex (that is what happens at overleaf) sorry I can not help with texmaker, I do not have it. @Thorek

Comment: Thank you for all that input. Since I am little short in time, I will probbably just generate the nomenclature online and than merge it with the main document for now.